# Icinga2 : Apt check notification

Tags: email, service, aptitude, icinga2

I got one question related to following facts :

1. On my server with icinga2 installed (with icinga2-web), I receive some critical notifications each 30min despite the fact that all packages are uptodate.
2. On the conf.d/apt.conf, I changed check_interval to once a week. I still receive one mail per 30 min.

Why do I still receive notification while packages uptodate and how can I change check interval?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be wrong...

1. forgot to relaod the icinga2 service
2. forgot to update-config on master server
3. or a unlimited recheck amount and the recheck intervall on 30mins